# Why does the tag <constructor> result in 'undefined' when using jQuery replaceWith()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm using jQuery to edit XML. Yes, I know that's probably a bad idea.

I came across some very strange behavior (a bug?) when using the xml tag `<constructor>`. Replacing existing XML with this tag results in the tag being surrounded by 'undefined'.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var my_xml = $.parseXML("<document><old>original xml</old></document>");
    var new_xml_string = '<constructor>Foobar</constructor>';
    var old_node = $(my_xml).find('old');
    old_node.replaceWith(new_xml_string);
    var my_xml_string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(my_xml);
    console.log(my_xml_string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code works fine for any other tag I try. So far only `<constructor>` seems to have this problem.

Any idea what's going on? Is this because jQuery is meant for processing HTML, not XML? Any workarounds I can use?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, yes. My guess would be they do some kind of `var validTags = {"a":true, "span":true, …}` and `"constructor" in validTags` is true. But yeah, you should in general use a [proper XML parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears as replacing `xml object` with `xml string`.
You should replace `xml object` with `xml object`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var my_xml = $.parseXML("<document><old>original xml</old></document>");
    var new_xml= $.parseXML("<document><constructor>Foo</constructor></document>");
    var new_xml_const = $(new_xml).find('constructor');
    var old_node = $(my_xml).find('old');
    old_node.replaceWith(new_xml_const);
    var my_xml_string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(my_xml);
    console.log(my_xml_string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```